# how can i make EventEmitter3 listener global in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I have a nextjs application in which i need to implement events. i am using EventEmitter3. i extended the EventEmitter library and made the extention into a singleton. i can cast events globally, but for some reason i cannot listen to events globally. i am using the same instance for both emitting and listeting to to event.

what i have so far.

```
import { EVENTS } from "./events"
import EventEmitter from "eventemitter3"


class Events extends EventEmitter {

    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    public emit(event: string | symbol, ...args: any[]): boolean {

        if (event in EVENTS) {
            return super.emit(event, ...args)
        }

        throw new Error(`Event ${String(event)} is not defined`)

    }

    public on(event: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this {

        if (event in EVENTS) {
            return super.on(event, listener)
        }

        throw new Error(`Event ${String(event)} is not defined`)
    }

    public once(event: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this {

        if (event in EVENTS) {
            return super.once(event, listener)
        }

        throw new Error(`Event ${String(event)} is not defined`)
    }

    public off(event: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this {

        return super.off(event, listener)

    }

    public removeListener(event: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this {

        return super.removeListener(event, listener)

    }

    public removeAllListeners(event?: string | symbol): this {

        return super.removeAllListeners(event)

    }

}

export const events = new Events()
```

then in nextjs api route, i do the following.

```
export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {

  events.emit(EVENTS.NEW_MESSAGE, { name: 'John' })

  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })

}
```

this works fine, but only if i listen for the event inside the api route or inside the same file as where i extend the EvenEmitter class.

is it possible to listen for events globally? becuase i can broadcast event globally.
if this is not possible with this library, please suggest alternatives.

thnx in advance.

Comment: How can `event in EVENTS` ever be true in your code?

Comment: event in EVENTS checks wether the event name exist in predefined object.

the **in** keyword is used to check for element in object. among other otherthings. its also handy for enums.